# Negative zero using Crystal Report ToText()

Tags: debugging, crystal-reports, windows-vista, crystal-reports-8.5

Using Crystal Reports 8.5 on Windows Vista or 7, I'm using the ToText function to report a value:

```
totext(Sum ({ap121w7.yrentamt}, {@type1099})*100,"000000000000000000")
```

The result (if yrentamt is 0) is -000000000000000000
The dash (I assume it's a negative sign) is unneccessary and unwanted in my report.  Is this a bug, or is there an easy solution?

--Note--

I would very much like to avoid the following:

```
if {ap121w7.yrentamt}=0.00 then
    yrentamt := "000000000000"
else
    yrentamt := totext({ap121w7.yrentamt}*100,"000000000000");
```

I have about 100 files to fix with multiple formulas per file, and the above solution doesn't seem to work consistently either.

Answer (score 1):

Looks ok - try using the Round() function on your number before calling ToText() - maybe your 0 value is actually some very tiny negative decimal.